# Something to visual CSS structures and compare them

Tags: css, ide, editor

I am looking for a tool to help with some CSS editing, but I am not planning to use it in what seems to be the normal way.

I have a website that is getting a reskin, we already have the CSS files with the changes as it is already applied to a related website.

What I ideally want, is an editor of some kind that will help me to visualize the structure or hierarchy of the old CSS and the new CSS so I can more easily find the classes that will cross over nicely, the classes that require tweaking, and the classes that will need to be created from scratch.

I'm not worried auto completion, or being able to view the changes instantly or anything like that, what i really want is just the easy way to view and traverse it.

Does anyone know of anything that can do this? Ideally free or open source, but all suggestions welcome.

Comment: How is this off topic? The faq states questions can be about 'software tools commonly used by programmers', and CSS is technically a programming language?

Comment: this actually could be quite useful imo; but I'm guessing it would be hard/impossible to correctly visualise descendant selectors as a tree structure

Comment: longshot....maybe css lint? im sure you could write/rewrite some of its functions to get your output.

Comment: This is a bit of a one off for me, so I don't really want to have to code anything up for it, thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tool: [Compare CSS Stylesheet Tool](http://www.alanhart.co.uk/archives/2010/12/15/compare-css-stylesheet-tool/)

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the closest thing I've seen yet, I'm going to leave the question open a bit longer though to see if anyone else has something.